# Eslint + typescript paths aliasing - Unable to resolve path to module

Tags: reactjs, eslint, tsconfig, react-tsx, typescript-eslint

I add typescript config for paths:

```
{
 //.....

 "moduleResolution": "node",
{
  "baseUrl": "app",
  "paths": {
  "@app/*": ["*"],
  "@folder/*": ["folder/*"],

  //Other paths
},
```

}

Added configuration to webpack:

```
  resolve: {
  extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx", ".css", ".json"],
  alias: {
    "@app":path.resolve(__dirname + "../", "app"),
    "@services":path.resolve(__dirname + "../app", "folder")
  },
  modules: [
    "node_modules", path.resolve(process.cwd(), "app")
  ],
  plugins: [
    new TsConfigPathsPlugin({
      configFile: "../tsconfig.json"
    }),
  ],
},
```

And here is my .eslint file:

```
"settings": {
"import/resolver": {
  "node": {
    "paths": [
      "app"
    ],
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".tsx",
      ".jest.tsx",
      ".d.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

After that I try import somthing like this:

```
import {component} from "@folder/component";
```

Everything is assembled, the compiler generates no errors
But I get error in eslint:

> ESLint: Unable to resolve path to module '@folder/component'.(import/no-unresolved)

I've been trying to figure this out for the third day
The customer does not want to install additional plugins
I would be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 7):

the `node` resolver doesn't understand TypeScript `paths`. So it's specifically looking for a node module called `@folder/component` - which won't exist.

You can use the typescript resolver for the plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript

Comment: thnx, that plugin resolver also worked for me